# Looking for a pure Python library for the SyncML protocol

Tags: python, syncml

I'm looking for an open source, pure Python library that supports the [SyncML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncML) protocol, at least enough to implement a SyncML client.

Comment: Similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226279/decoding-a-wbxml-syncml-message-from-an-s60-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's https://sourceforge.net/projects/pysyncml/: "The pysyncml library is a pure-python implementation of the SyncML adapter framework and protocol." Haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pure Python implementations, but there are python bindings for C libraries:

- pysyncml (google for it, can only post 1 link) and
- a [ctypes-based wrapper](http://github.com/Jc2k/conduit/blob/8beabdb62bccda57a9d49917ead305e611203a26/conduit/modules/SyncmlModule/pysyncml.py) that's used by the conduit project.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of these. I'd rather have a pure Python library to prevent having to distribute different versions of the libraries for different Python versions. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can across an implementation of syncml used by the ERP5 project
It is used to sync with mobile devices
[link text](http://www.erp5.org/HowToUseERP5SyncMLWithAMobilePhone)

Comment: Thanks for the link. The code is here: http://svn.erp5.org/erp5/trunk/products/ERP5SyncML/. Unfortunately it is not a standalone library.